# Is it a good practice to use JdbcTemplate.update() to execute a stored proc?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

Currently I am using `JdbcTemplate.update()` method to execute a stored proc which basically update and inserts some records and it
doesnt return anything.
But I am not sure whether its a good practice to use `update()` method to execute a stored proc. Is there any drawback of using that method?
or do i have to use `execute()` method ? I am trying to avoid implementing execute() since it will require lot of code changes in my application.

**Code :**

```
jdbcTemplate.update("call test_stored_proc(? , ?)", new Long[] {
                    userId, statusId });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use whichever you wish for this. `execute` is kind of general API that can run anything and lets you know what kind of result it returns (result set or number of affected rows). `update` is a special version for queries that either return affected rows or nothing at all.

`JdbcTemplate` delegates the query ultimately to `java.sql.Statement`.

From [java.sql.Statement Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> **executeUpdate(String sql):**
>   Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.
>
> **execute(String sql):**
>   Executes the given SQL statement, which may return multiple results.

Comment: So 'update()' internally calls `Statement.executeUpdate()` method ?

Comment: Ok. Got it . Its calling `Statement.executeUpdate()`. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using basic Spring jdbc support, you should use SimpleJdbcCall for calling stored procedures, as that helps you with the metadata associated with these type of calls. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

But personally I'd use the @Procedure annotations in Spring Data JPA which makes things a lot easier. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.stored-procedures

so your code changes to calling a method on an interface something like this:

```
@Procedure("test_stored_proc")
public void callIt(long userId, statusId);
```

Note that you'll have to set up Spring JPARepository support in your app for this to work.